# Get multiline text from textarea with Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium

I need to get multiline text from textarea element of web-page. I see in Chrome developer tool that text I need is stored in *value* property of textarea.
[I marked it on screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcZ9E.png)

Below is fragment of page source:

```
<div id="team1">
 <div id="lineupsPanel1" style="display: block;">
  <textarea id="lineupsField1" placeholder="Enter text for analyze here"></textarea>
  <button onclick="viewLineupsInTable(1,1)" title="Process text" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; color: red; padding: 3px 6px; margin: 0px 4px
  0px 0px;">Process</button>
```

I try below code to get text from *value* property

```vb
Set WebElemTextBox = Chrome.FindElementById("lineupsField1")
If Not (WebElemTextBox Is Nothing) Then
    TextVar = WebElemTextBox.value
End If
```

But so *TextVar* gets only first line of stored text (on screenshot example
 `value: "Next items are not found:↵↵Pam-pam↵↵Next items are found:↵↵Monitor"`
But *TextVar* gets only `"Next items are not found:"` ).

How to get full multiline text?

I also found some answers to use something like
`TextVar = WebElemTextBox.getAttribute("value")`

But I get
`"Run-time error: 438. Object doesn't support this property or method"`
on that string while testing.

UPDATE. I figured out the problem myself:
When you watch value of the variable by moving cursor to it - then for string variable is showing only first line of text without any mark (three dots or something else). We should use Watch Window instead to not to be cheated.
So method `TextVar = WebElemTextBox.value` works well.

Comment: Have you tried `.innertext` or `.innerhtml`?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: I added screenshot from Chrome and fragment of page source for clarity.

Comment: So just checking, if you debug.print TextVar are you sure you're not getting the full value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself:

When you watch value of the variable by moving cursor to it - then for string variable is showing only first line of text without any mark (three dots or something else). We should use **Watch Window** instead to not to be cheated. So method
`TextVar = WebElemTextBox.value` works well.

Answer (score 1):

If possible posting the HTML would be helpful, but I'll try answering it anyway.

First Check your element Id for each line you wish to make into a string, I'm assuming they are sequential. Something like "lineupsField1", "lineupsField2", lineupsField3" etc.

If so you can loop through and append these values to a string. Ex:

```
For i = 1 to 10
    Set WebElemTextBox = Chrome.FindElementById("lineupsField" & i)
    If Not (WebElemTextBox Is Nothing) Then
        TextVar = TextVar & WebElemTextBox.value
    End If
Next
```

If the element Id's are not in sequential order than instead of looping just append till you reach your goal. Ex:

```
Set WebElemTextBox = Chrome.FindElementById("lineupsField1")
    If Not (WebElemTextBox Is Nothing) Then
        TextVar = TextVar & WebElemTextBox.value
    End If

Set WebElemTextBox = Chrome.FindElementById("Element2")
    If Not (WebElemTextBox Is Nothing) Then
        TextVar = TextVar & WebElemTextBox.value
    End If
```

As far as the other method you showed:

```
TextVar = WebElement.getAttribute("value")
```

I wouldn't recommend going down this path as you are likely going to create more work for yourself parsing through all the values in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your option. But your guess about sequential elements with text is not right. I added screenshot and fragment of page source in my question for clarity.